# VueRouter omitting the forward slash before the # in non-history mode

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-5.4, vue-router

i'm trying to use **VueRouter** `2.2.1` in my **Laravel** application and for some reason my URL's *(although working)* show the # symbol in a weird way

```
http://myapp.dev/admin#/
```

Instead of

```
http://myapp.dev/admin/#/
```

As i would normally expect...

This is my **VueRouter** configuration

```
const Router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            component: App,
            children: [
                {
                    path: 'dashboard',
                    name: 'dashboard',
                    component: Dashboard
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

And on the PHP side of things i'm just defining a **catch all** route for the `/admin` section of the *Application*

```
    // Catch-all Route, sends GET requests to VueRouter //
    Route::get('{all?}', function() {
        return view('index');
    })->where(['all' => '(.*)'])->name('catchall');
```

Like this, is there anything i'm doing wrong? It is working but it just kinda bugs me that the # just floats there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable history mode, as stated  [here](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html), I dont see that in your vue-router config.

```
const Router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            component: App,
            children: [
                {
                    path: 'dashboard',
                    name: 'dashboard',
                    component: Dashboard
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: i **HAVE** to set history mode? I would prefer not using it, i used Angular before and it worked like i stated `/#/` and then whatever your URI was, in VueJS this is impossible then?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it on server side, just redirect the route to one ended with `'/'`

As in laravel:

```
Route::get('{all?}', function() {
    return view('index');
})->where(['all' => '^/admin\/$'])->name('catchall');
```

now just visit `/admin/#/`